# 1 NIC - Two VMs on different VLANS

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware

I have currently a trunk port connected on one host that runs VMWare Workstation 14. I would like to have 2 VMs running on that host and each one to be part of a different VLAN.

My VLANS are: VLAN10 - 172.0.10.0/24 and VLAN20 172.0.20.0/24.

On my host, on my NIC configuration I was able to set the VLAN ID and be part of the VLAN, which means my trunk works.

How can I setup my VMs now to use those VLANs? Note: The host should not be part of any VLAN, only the VMs.
Our environment cannot support 2 different NICs. Only one NIC should be used.

I spent a lot of time reading on the internet but there is not a clear answer if Workstation supports that or how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution,

1. "you must also disable "Priority & VLAN" on the HOSTS LAN adapter that you are bridging... otherwise it drops all of the packets that contain tags targeting the VM"
2. You need to add a new Network under Edit-> Virtual Network Editor and select VMnet3. Then Under VMnet Information Select Bridged and choose your NIC.
3. "switching to the vmxnet3 paravirtualized NIC gave the option for VLAN tagging in the driver's advanced settings.  Just change ethernet0.virtualDev to "vmxnet3" in your VM's .vmx file"
4. In the VM go to NIC's Advanced settings and set the VLAN ID tagging.
   IT WORKS!

[Source](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2667304#2667304)